# Elasticsearch: Update mapping field type ID from long to string

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, mapping, filtering

I changed the elasticsearch mapping field type from:

```
    "articles": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
              "type": "long"
          }}}
```

to

```
     "articles": {
        "properties": {
           "id": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           }
```

After that I did the following steps:

1. **Create the index with new mapping**
2. **Reindex the mapping to the new index**

After the mapping update my previous query filter doesn't work anymore and I have no results:

```
GET /art/_search
{
    "query": {
    "filtered": {
         "query": {
        "match_all": {}
        },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                      {
                      "type": {
                      "value": "articles"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                      "term": {
                      "id": "123467679"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 1,
   "sort": [
      {
          "_score": "desc"
      }
   ]
}
```

If I check with this query the result is what I expect:

```
GET /art/articles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I would appreciate if somebody have some idea why after the field type change the query is no longer working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the query was with ID filter.
The query works correctly changing the filter from:

```
"term": {
         "id": "123467679"
        }
```

in:

```
"term": {
         "_id": "123467679"
        }
```

I'm still a beginner with elasticsearch to figure out why the mapping change broke the query although I did the reindex, but "_id" fixed my query.

You can find more informations in the :
[elasticsearch mapping reference documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html).